# Приём по CAN идущих подряд сообщений

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

Добрый день, столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при приёме по CAN нескольких идущих подряд сообщений, часть из них теряется. Идея системы: есть некое головное устройство, в данном случае это RPi 3, подключённый к CAN через модуль MCP2515. Также есть исполнительные устройства, в данном случае это STM32F767ZIT, также подключенные к CAN. Для опроса исполнительных устройств, головное устройство посылает в CAN общую команду, а исполнительные сразу же на него отвечают. Условный номер исполнительного устройства "вшит" в индификатор ответного сообщения, благодаря чему ответные сообщения пересылаются по шине по очереди согласно протоколу СAN. Анализатором проверяю шину, всё так, как и задумано. Но вот головное устройство не успевает, похоже что, принять все ответные сообщения. Поскольку вместо ответных сигналов от, скажем, первого, пятого и седьмого устройства, оно получает лишь от первого и седьмого. А во время следующего цикла проверки от пятого и седьмого. Так в чём же дело? Буфер MCP2515 переполняется? Или библиотека CAN для RPi кривая? В этом случае хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение по поводу наиболее подходящей библиотеки CAN для RPi на c++ или си. Данная проблема не зависит от скорости передачи по CAN, наблюдал её как при 125 кб/с так и при 500 кб/с. Думал задержку поставить в исполнительных устройствах при отправлении ответного сигнала, но это бессмысленно, поскольку возможна ситуация когда приходится им отправлять и "неответные" сигналы и опять создать очередь из нескольких сообщений. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

MCP2515 - это буфер аж под два сообщения.
Соответственно, если RPi не успевает их вычитывать, всё остальное теряется.

Беглый гуглёж показывает, что нужна какая-то магия с параметрами ядра, чтобы сделать быстрые прерывания и быстрый SPI ("быстрые" - в смысле "с малым временем реакции").
Какие-то вменяемые исследования, сколько в итоге получилось, я сходу не нашёл.

Выводы:

- вариант 1: настраивать драйвера под этот MCP2515. Для понимания времени реакции очень рекомендую смотреть происходящее через Saleae (достаточно самого дешёвого клона).
- вариант 2: сделать на какой-нибудь STM'ке с CAN'ом более сообразительный адаптер, благо Вы эти STM'ки "умеете" :) Простенькая STM32F105 не напрягаясь транслирует 500-ю шину, потерь замечено не было.